# two date slicers in same powerbi page

Tags: matrix, powerbi, slicers

I've created:

- two different DATE slicers,
- each slicer selecting a year from two different Calendar tables,
- each Calendar table is in a relationship with the [ReservationDate] field of the MainData table.

I need each slicer to determine the date of one matrix visual each.

HOWEVER, when I select the date from the first slicer, both matrix visuals automatically change to that selection, rendering the second slicer useless.

NOTE: From the 'Edit Interactions' menu option, I've restricted the first matrix to be filtered by only the first slicer and the second matrix to be filtered by only the second slicer.  But that is not helping.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Start over with a simple repro.  What you are describing will work fine.  If you have trouble with the simple repro post the details as part of your question.